# I can't go to the page archive-{post_type}.php

Tags: php, css, html, archive-template

Is my custom post type on function.php

```
add_action('init', 'create_objects_type');
function create_objects_type() {
    register_post_type('objects',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'               => __('Недвижимость'),
                'singular_name'      =>  __('Недвижимость'),
                'add_new'            => __('Добавить Недвижимость'),
                'add_new_item'       => __('Добавление Недвижимости'),
                'edit'              =>  __('Редактировать Недвижимость'),
                'edit_item'          => __('Редактирование Недвижимости'),
                'new_item'           => __('Новая Недвижимость'),
                'view'                   => __('Просмотреть Недвижимость'),
                'view_item'          => __('Просмотреть Недвижимость'),
                'search_items'       => __('Поиск по Недвижимости'),
                'not_found'          => __('Пока нет Недвижимости'),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __('В корзине нет Недвижимости'),
                'menu_name'          => __('Недвижимость'),
            ),
            'description'         => 'Недвижимость itip',
            'public'              => true,
            'publicly_queryable'  => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui'             => true,
            'show_in_menu'        => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
            'menu_position'       => 20,
            'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-store', 
            'capability_type'       => 'post',
            'map_meta_cap'          => true,
            'hierarchical'        => false,
            'supports' => array(
                    'title',
                    'page-attributes',
                    'post-formats',
                    'custom-fields'
                ),
            // 'taxonomies'          => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive'         => true,
            'rewrite'             => true,
            'query_var'           => true,
            'can_export'          => true
        )
    );
}
```

And added new taxonomy

```
function wptp_register_taxonomy() {
  register_taxonomy( 'objects_category', 'objects',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name'              => 'Article Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Article Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Article Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'All Article Categories',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Article Categories',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Article Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Article Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Article Category Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Article Category',
        ),
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'sort' => true,
      'args' => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
      'show_admin_column' => true
      )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptp_register_taxonomy' );
```

This is navigation in index.php

```
  <?
    wp_nav_menu( [
        'theme_location'  => '',
        'menu'            => 'Главное Меню', 
        'container'       => false, 
        'container_class' => '',
        'container_id'    => '',
        'menu_class'      => 'main_nav', 
        'menu_id'         => '',
        'echo'            => true,
        'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
        'before'          => '',
        'after'           => '',
        'link_before'     => '',
        'link_after'      => '',
        'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
        'depth'           => 0,
        'walker'          => '',
    ] );
    ?>
```

This is menu in inspector

```
<ul id="menu-glavnoe-menyu-1" class="main_nav"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-19"><a href="http://design/category/kvartiry/">квартиры <span class="count">0</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-18"><a href="http://design/category/doma/">дома <span class="count">1</span></a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-20"><a href="http://design/category/ofisy/">офисы <span class="count">1</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Items of menu is categories

I have page taxonomy-objects_category.php

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Каталог
*/
?>
<?php get_header();?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

When I click to the item of menu wordpress no go to the taxonomy-objects_category.php. He show me page 404.php
How I can solve this problem?
In this screen you can see hierarchy. Is need to devide posts "objects" in 3 categories:

[image]

Comment: native WP templates don't require the ```Template Name``` comment block.

Comment: `http://design/category/doma/` is **not** an objects post archive, _it is a `doma` category archive_. I recommend spending some time looking at the template hierarchy diagram.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: As Tom hinted, `category` is actually a taxonomy and will use the taxonomy archive template instead of the post type one... you may want to have both if you want to assign the `category` taxonomy to this post type like this, otherwise you might consider giving the post type it's own custom taxonomy also and a template specifically for that.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: @Denis, maybe you just need to flush the rewrite rules - just visit the Permalink Settings admin page (Settings → Permalinks).